# Kucoin How to Get Order Book for futures from api?

Tags: python, api, kucoin, requests-futures

I'm trying to find how to get futures order book for all tickers, i successfully found how to get active contracts using : https://api-futures.kucoin.com/api/v1/contracts/active

I read the api documentation, it says

Get Order Book

HTTP Request
GET /api/v2/order-book

```
kucoinf = requests.get("https://api-futures.kucoin.com/api/v2/order-book")
e = kucoinf.json()
kucoinf = json_normalize(e['data'])
print (kucoinf)
```

but it doesn't work https://api-futures.kucoin.com/api/v2/order-book

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use the [CCXT library](https://docs.ccxt.com/en/latest/exchange-markets.html) as it will make your life easier for what you are trying to do.

To retrieve Kucoin **spot** market order book:

```
import ccxt

exchange = ccxt.kucoin()

symbol = 'BTC/USDT'
order_book = exchange.fetchOrderBook(symbol)
print(order_book)
```

To retrieve Kucoin **futures** market order book:

```
import ccxt

exchange = ccxt.kucoinfutures()

symbol = 'BTC/USDT:USDT'
order_book = exchange.fetchOrderBook(symbol)
print(order_book)
```